# Сохранение и восстановление проекта на MS VS 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Добрый день.

Есть проект С++ на MS VS 2017. Проект состоит из 12 cpp файлов и 1 хедера. В редакторе открыты все 13 файлов. Однако, когда я вечером выхожу из VS 2017, а на следующий день снова загружаю проект, то хедер в редакторе не открывается. Вот такая беда - cpp файлы открываются автоматически, а хедер приходится открывать самому.

Вопрос:

1. Где надо поставить птичку и какому микрософтовскому Богу помолиться, чтобы ВСЕ файлы проекта открывались в редакторе после загрузки проекта.

Спасибо.

UPD1:

Оказалось, что если явно включить хедер в проект, то он сохраняется в редакторе после перезапуска проекта. Интересно, теперь что же, невозможно сохранять в редакторе файл, не относящийся к проекту?

Comment: Очевидно, если файл не является частью проекта, то он считается просто открытым файлом, не относящимся к проекту. Вы ж можете в Visual Studio просто открыть файл на редактирование, вне всякого проекта. Вангую, что когда вы _закрывали_ проект, это header оставался всё равно открытым.

Comment: Не наблюдаю такого поведения, все файлы всегда переоткрываются про открытии проекта. Даже есть они не относятся непосредственно к проекту, и даже если они не относятся к зависимостям проекта.

Comment: [все файлы всегда переоткрываются про открытии проекта] У меня тоже все работало, а со вчерашнего дня сломалось. Вот я и спрашиваю, где в VS 2017 слетела настройка, которая отвечает за сохранение редактируемых файлов.

Comment: Может у вас файл с состоянием проекта был поврежден как-то? Попробуйте удалить папку `.vs` (в папке решения).